# ¿Cómo se utiliza interpolatenull con un gráfico Candlestick?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Estoy mostrando valores con un grafico tipo **Candlestick** con **google chart**. Por el momento elimino los datos faltantes pero seria mejor indicar la falta de datos usando **interpolatenull**. He visto ejemplos con gráficos de linea pero ninguno con candlestick. ¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interporlateNulls` es un parámetro de configuración de los gráficos de línea pero **no** de los gráficos Candlestick, así que no puedes usarlo para "indicar la falta de datos".

Referencias:

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#configuration-options
- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options

Comment: Gracias por la informacion!